# Image_Picker - image does not display if I use split

Tags: flutter, uiimagepickercontroller

I do not understand why line //1 is not working properly, I mean I can't display the picture taken, but the line //2 works fine. I do not understand why. My objective is to remove from the path the mention "image_picker_".

```
if (pickedFile != null) {
        File imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
        setState(() {
    //1      filesGB.add(pickedFile.path.toString().split('image_picker_').last);
    //2      filesGB.add(pickedFile.path.toString());
        });
      }
```

Comment: It doesn't display because "image_picker_" is part of the file path, so if you remove it you no longer have the path to the file (obviously). If you want to change the path, then you first need to save the file at the path you want. Line //1 is giving you a path to nothing because you haven't saved the file at that path.

Comment: Many thanks. Makes sense. I will study this and decided if I keep image_picker in the path or if I record the file and change the file path